# Picasso not loading the image

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

here's the code for picasso:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.product_image);
    Picasso.with(this)
    .load(_url)
    .fit()
    .into(img, new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {


        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {


        }
    });
```

here's the value of _url: 
    http://kiagallery.ir/Images/Upload/Collection%20101/Spring%20101/d4a03b66dc7b46c694615c549b78b2e9.jpg

and here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/product_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/product_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:layout_below="@id/product_image"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:layout_below="@id/product_name"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

as you can see the image can be accessed via browser but picasso fails to load it, I've checked the onError function and it's never called, I'm quiet lost here, any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** When I give imageview's width & height fixed value like 200dp, it loads the image, but when I change it to wrap_content it doesn't show the image.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

My guess is you should *not* call that `fit()` method in Picasso while your `ImageView` has its width and height defined by `WRAP_CONTENT`.

This method wait until the `ImageView` has been measured and resize the image to exactly match it's size. While your `ImageView` is having size defined by `WRAP_CONTENT`, then methods `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()` seemingly returns 0 which is making your `ImageView` *invisible*.

Comment: yea, as it's mentioned in https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/457 ... so I'll removed the fit() call, and will fix the width of my image to 90% of the device, that should fix it

Comment: I have exactly the same code but it still doesn't load it. I've changed also the width and height to 200dp and added permission to Manifest File, what can be the possible problems?

Answer (score 61):

Do not forget add permission to manifest

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Omg! I missed to add this also!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE) then it might possible that you will not get images using Picasso.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue where I had a `ViewPager` of images placed inside a fullscreen `DialogFragment`. The same ViewPager worked perfectly when placed elsewhere and Picasso loaded the images as expected. But only when placed in the fullscreen `DialogFragment`, some images would appear blank. It seemed that images were successfully fetched from server and loaded into the `ImageView`, but the `ImageView` was still appearing blank.

None of the above answers or similar threads worked for me.

So I switched to another great library called [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). It is pretty much similar to Picasso.
Find out more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide) and [here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en).
Even though this might not be the most relevant answer, it might be worth giving a shot for someone who has been stuck with a similar problem.