# Picasso .fit().centerCrop() not working with WRAP_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso, android-image, android-layoutparams

I have an `ImageView` that I create programmatically, and load an image into using Picasso.  The height and width of the ImageView are set to `WRAP_CONTENT`.  The image is pretty large, so I want to use Picasso's `.fit().centerCrop()` methods in order to save memory.  However, when I add the methods, the images don't show up, and I think it must be because of `WRAP_CONTENT`. Here's my code:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(getContext());
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams centerParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
iv.setLayoutParams(centerParams);
Picasso.with(context)load(path).fit().centerCrop().into(iv); //if I remove .fit().centerCrop(), the images load just fine
```

The only info I could find on this was [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/457) about it -- while the issue says it was closed in v2.4, some people have commented saying that they are experiencing it in v2.5.  (I'm using v2.5 as well)

**EDIT**:  Here's what I'm using now, per Angela's suggestion:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(getContext());
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams centerParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dpToPx(350));
centerParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
iv.setLayoutParams(centerParams);
iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);                                    
iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(path).fit().into(iv);
```

The images now show up, but they aren't scaling properly, the aspect ratio gets changed somehow.  Any ideas on how to preserve aspect ratio while still allowing Picasso to get a measurement for `.fit()`?

Comment: Do not use picasso's fit() method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114045/picasso-not-loading-the-image

Answer (score 7):

I also encountered that problem. Here's what I did...

```
            Picasso
                    .with(context)
                    .load(path)
                    .fit()
                    .into(iv);
```

In the xml file try to include scaleType, adjustViewBounds, and layout_gravity
for example:

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_movie"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks!  :)  Images load now, but I can't get them scaling properly, the aspect ratio keeps getting changed -- updated code above.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(path).fit().centerInside().into(iv);
```

or

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(path).fit().centerCrop().into(iv);
```