# Android Picasso "fit().centerCrop()" doesn't load image

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso

I want to display image (URL) into my imageview as max width and variable height    according to width size, when I use this code part:

```
imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Picasso.with(context).load(product.getImage()).into(imageView);
```

I can display my image into imageview. I also tried use **resize().centerCrop()** methods and it worked successfully.

But however, when I use

> Picasso.with(context).load(product.getImage()).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);

or

> Picasso.with(context).load(product.getImage()).fit().centerInside().into(imageView);

my imageview display nothing. I don't understand why. Maybe the problem my list design and imageview. Here is my **list_content_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.80"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_stats"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried set **wrap_content** and **match_parent**  both of ImageView's width and height and it didn't worked, too. Where am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use logging to see trace of picasso using `Picasso.with(context).setLoggingEnabled(true);` You can put this line into your `Application` to log in entire app or just into your Activity/Fragment.

Comment: do not use fit() method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114045/picasso-not-loading-the-image

Comment: because you use fit and center crop together you must use one of them .A sample image can fitted or center crop not together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`adjustViewBounds` does the trick:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

I find it easier to configure this behavior using XML attributes rather than Picasso methods.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I updated my imageview like this and changed my code like this: **Picasso.with(context).load(product.getImage()).into(imageView);**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are not adding a `.` before using `fit()`.
Replace you code with this: 
 `Picasso.with(context).load(product.getImage()).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView`)

As an Alternative
you can also define the scaletype to your imageView using`android:scaleType="fitXY"`
In youn xml file.

Then get your image into imageview: `Picasso.with(context).load(product. getImage).fit().into(imageView);`

Comment: I tried. But it didn't work. imageview shows nothing again.

Answer (score 0):

public Builder resize(int targetWidth, int targetHeight)

> Resize the image to the specified size in pixels.
>   Use 0 as desired dimension to resize keeping aspect ratio.

use this.

```
fun Fragment.getDeviceWidth(): Int {
    val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
    requireActivity().windowManager.defaultDisplay.getRealMetrics(displayMetrics)

    return displayMetrics.widthPixels
}


.resize(getDeviceWidth(), 0)
```