# ImageView image not showing after loading with Picaso and linking to layout file

Tags: android, picasso

I want to show a radio button and next to it show a ImageView with image loaded by Picaso. I tried putting the ImageView object after loading it next to the radio button in Relative layout but only the radio button is showing up but not the the image. I am new to android and any help is appreciated. can anyone point out the issue?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test.imageslider;



import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;

    private String[] imageUrls = {"https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png",
            "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png",
            "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        //ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);

        //viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        ImageView imageView;

        //this will set the image to your ImageView in your xml
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImage);

        Picasso.get()
                .load(imageUrls[0])
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(imageView);
        RadioGroup ll = new RadioGroup(this);
        RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
        rdbtn.setId(View.generateViewId());
        ll.addView(rdbtn);
        ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup)).addView(ll);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.test.imageslider.MainActivity">

    <!--<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/> -->


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </RadioGroup>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myImage" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: your ImageView is overlapping over RadioGroup

Comment: Do not use picasso's fit() method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114045/picasso-not-loading-the-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Give `height` and `weight` to `ImageView`. I have tested it and works fine,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/> -->


    <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </RadioGroup>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myImage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radiogroup"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your Layout because radiobutton overlaps imageview

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   android:orientation="vertical"

      >
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</RadioGroup>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/myImage" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I did set the permission. I had picasso working fine when I tested it with viewpager. i don't need viewpager now because now i only have one image and a radio button

Comment: It's not fair to use someone's idea as your own

Answer (score 0):

It seems your ImageView is overlapping over RadioGroup! It's my recommensation for **activity_main.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.test.imageslider.MainActivity">

    <!--<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/> -->


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </RadioGroup>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radiogroup" />
</RelativeLayout>/>
```

You can edit it on your own.

Hope it works!

P.S: I have edited activity_main.xml file out of IDE and may have some typo, so correct it if you found some :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `ImageView` is overlapping over `RadioGroup`! It's my recommendation for `activity_main.xml` file: `app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"` will replace with your image .

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>


    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_below="@id/viewPager"
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Demo"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Demo"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Demo"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Demo"/>



    </RadioGroup>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/radiogroup"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />
</RelativeLayout>
```